# SharePoint without buying Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business, onedrive, collaboration

How can I used only SharePoint Online and OneDrive without buying Office365.

I just want to use for central document sharing on Cloud. I don't want local installation.

If it is possible, how much it will cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to understand SharePoint online is one of the service under office 365 subscription. It has exchange, Lync etc other than the SharePoint online, it all depends on the subscription what you are opting for.

Yes, you can subscribe to office 365 with just SharePoint online and OneDrive plan where your license cost will be less.

If you are not planning for SharePoint on-premise, you don't need to install anything.

**Cost** :

SharePoint Online user license cost Rs.(INR) 330 user/month.

**Products under this license**

Sharepoint online &  OneDrive

Office Applications (not included)

**Plan Name** : SharePoint Online Plan 1

**Other notable features under this plan**:

- 1 TB of OneDrive storage per user
- Share files securely inside or outside your organization
- Sync local copies of files or folders for offline viewing and editing on Mac or PC
- Co-author in real time in familiar Microsoft Office apps
- Inform and connect your people with intranets and portals
- Tell your story with beautiful communication sites
- Use team sites to connect teams to content, expertise, and processes
- Organize and manage content in libraries and lists with metadata, records management, and retention policies
- Move and manage files between OneDrive and SharePoint
- Search and discover relevant people and important content when you need it most
- Navigate your team sites and intranet with the SharePoint mobile apps for Android™, iOS, and Windows or OneDrive mobile apps for Android™, iOS and Windows5
- FastTrack deployment support with purchase of 50+ seats at no extra cost
- 24/7 phone and web support
- Licensed for commercial use

For details information about this plan is here :

[Compare SharePoint Online options](https://products.office.com/en-in/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans)

Comment: I’d to know one more thing. How about data backups and restore?  Is it easy to manage in share point online? Thanks

Comment: It is completely managed by Microsoft.. for any query you can raise ticket to Microsoft from the admin center, someone from the support will contact to you within just 10 minutes... we don't need to worry about any backup, they will take care.

Comment: okay thanks again!